# GET Api response using Go Lang's GIN

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm newbie to go lang and gin framework.
I'm trying to get a response of the code below.
Can someone pls guide me what mistake I'm doing?

```
func main() {
router := gin.Default()
router.GET("/foo", func(c *gin.Context) {
    response, err := http.Get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    if err != nil || response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        c.Status(http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
        return
    }
    reader := response.Body
    fmt.Println("Test", reader)

    c.JSON(200, reader)
})
router.Run("")
}
```

Response is empty.

This is the actual response
curl -X GET "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are doing, you may be better of using [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#ReverseProxy). But that only works if you don't need to work with the upstream response or manipulate it. Otherwise, you need to read the body with something like [ioutil.ReadAll](https://docs.studygolang.com/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) or even decode it into a struct.

```
router.GET("/foo", func(c *gin.Context) {
    response, err := http.Get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    if err != nil {
        c.Status(http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
        return
    }
    
    // if there was no error, you should close the body
    defer response.Body.Close()    
     
    // hence this condition is moved into its own block
    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        c.Status(http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
        return
    }
    
    // use a proper struct type in your real code
    // the empty interface is just for demonstration
    var v interface{}
    json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&v)
    fmt.Println("Test", v)

    c.JSON(200, v)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here defined a struct to bind reponce
type Responce struct {
UserID uint   `json:"userId"`
Id     uint   `json:"id"`
Title  string `json:"title"`
Body   string `json:"body"`
}

```
r.GET("/foo", func(c *gin.Context) {
    response, err := http.Get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    if err != nil || response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        c.Status(http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
        return
    }
    var resp Responce

    json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&resp)
    fmt.Println("Test", resp)

    c.JSON(200, resp)
})
```